# Will has_many :through impose huge performance impact in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's consider the following relationships (3 models):

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authorships
    has_many :papers, :through => :authorships
end
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authorships, inverse_of: :paper, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :authors, :through => :authorships
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :authorships, :allow_destroy => true
end
class Authorship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :paper
    belongs_to :author
    validate: rank, presence: true  # position of the author
end
```

As you can see, I use a lot `has_many` and also `:through`. When I browse `paper.html.erb` page which basically shows all the papers and corresponding authors, it slows down the system a lot. Right now I have roughly 400 papers and 2000 authorships, and it takes 3 seconds to load the page, plus, from the log I saw RoR made a lot of SQL queries, the majority of the queries are to retrieve authors. I was wondering this is a typical thing in RoR. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you also post your controller and view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like more of an optimization problem. To answer your original question, has_many :through by itself does NOT cause any noticeable difference. You would have the exact same problem if you only only had two tables for `Paper` and `Authorship`.

Based on what you reported about your logs, I assume your code looks something like this:

```
# Controller:
@papers = Paper.all

# View:
<% @papers.each do |paper| %>
    <%= paper.authors.join(', ') %>
    <%# other code... %>
<% end %>
```

What rails does is for every time you call `paper.authors`, it will run a query to fetch the authors associated with that paper. If you have 400 papers, rails will run 400 queries. This is called the n+1 query problem, where n queries are run for each record, along with the first query to get the initial records. Rails has a nice guide on how to tackle this issue: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

You basically want to avoid running a query every time you want to get the authors for a paper. You could instead load your papers in the controller like this: `@papers = Paper.includes(:author).all`. This would load all the papers along with their associated authors and only run 2 queries: one for all the papers, and another for all the authors associated with those papers.

However, be careful with overusing `.includes` because it could also slow down your loading time once you have too many records. Rails also takes time to create each `Paper` and each `Author` object in memory; it would currently be creating 2,400 objects based on your database records. After you get to a certain number of records, you should look into adding pagination or search functionality instead of loading tens of thousands of records on a single page.

Comment: I think you mean :authors, but yeah it speeds up a lot!